# Error while inserting date and time in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am getting error while inserting data and time into the sq-lite database, I get the error when I inserted date time column in my table.

```
package com.example.moneymanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Lending extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button sqlAdd;
    EditText sqlName, sqlAmount, sqlRate, sqlTime;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lending);

        sqlAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        sqlAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
        sqlRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRate);
        sqlTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTime);

        sqlAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    } //oncreate
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean didItWork = true;
        try{
        String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
        String amount = sqlAmount.getText().toString();
        String rate = sqlRate.getText().toString();
        String time = sqlTime.getText().toString();
        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
             new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);

        LendDatabase entry = new LendDatabase(Lending.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name, amount, rate, time, currentTime);
        entry.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            didItWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Dang it!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }finally{
            if(didItWork){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Heck Yea!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    }//onclick



}





package com.example.moneymanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class LendDatabase {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "persons_amount";
    public static final String KEY_RATE = "persons_rate";   //rate of interest
    public static final String KEY_TIME = "persons_time";   //time in months for which money is lend
    public static final String KEY_TIMEST = "time_of_lending"; //current date and time 

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Lendingdb1";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE );*/

            arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_RATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TIMEST + "DATETIME NOT NULL);"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(arg0);

        }
    }

        public LendDatabase(Context c){
            ourContext = c;
        }

        public LendDatabase open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
        }
        public void close(){
            ourHelper.close();
        }

        public long createEntry(String name, String amount, String rate,
                String time, String currentTime) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
            cv.put(KEY_RATE, rate);
            cv.put(KEY_TIME, time);
            cv.put(KEY_TIMEST, currentTime);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }

        public String getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_RATE, KEY_TIME, KEY_TIMEST};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            String result = "";

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
            int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT);
            int iRate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_RATE);
            int iTime = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME);
            int iTimest = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMEST);

            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                result = result + c.getString(iRow) + ".Name    :" + c.getString(iName) + "\n  Amount   :" + c.getString(iAmount) + "\n  Rate   :" + c.getString(iRate) + "\n  Time :" + c.getString(iTime) + "\n  Time :" + c.getString(iTimest) + "\n";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here is the logcat:

```
07-28 21:33:50.983: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): No keyboard for id 0
07-28 21:33:50.994: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-28 21:34:12.384: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table peopleTable has no column named time_of_lending
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274): Error inserting time_of_lending=2014-07-28 21:34:12 persons_rate=665 persons_amount=2131 persons_time=4 persons_name=asdf
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table peopleTable has no column named time_of_lending: , while compiling: INSERT INTO peopleTable(time_of_lending, persons_rate, persons_amount, persons_time, persons_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.example.moneymanager.LendDatabase.createEntry(LendDatabase.java:81)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.example.moneymanager.Lending.onClick(Lending.java:49)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274): Error inserting time_of_lending=2014-07-28 21:34:12 persons_rate=665 persons_amount=2131 persons_time=4 persons_name=asdf
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table peopleTable has no column named time_of_lending: , while compiling: INSERT INTO peopleTable(time_of_lending, persons_rate, persons_amount, persons_time, persons_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.example.moneymanager.LendDatabase.createEntry(LendDatabase.java:81)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.example.moneymanager.Lending.onClick(Lending.java:49)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 21:34:12.443: E/Database(274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:20.873: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: time_of_lending
07-28 21:34:20.873: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM
07-28 21:34:20.883: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moneymanager/com.example.moneymanager.LendingView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: time_of_lending: , while compiling: SELECT _id, persons_name, persons_amount, persons_rate, persons_time, time_of_lending FROM peopleTable
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: time_of_lending: , while compiling: SELECT _id, persons_name, persons_amount, persons_rate, persons_time, time_of_lending FROM peopleTable
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.example.moneymanager.LendDatabase.getData(LendDatabase.java:88)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.example.moneymanager.LendingView.onCreate(LendingView.java:17)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-28 21:34:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  ... 11 more
07-28 21:34:26.283: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 9
```

I have the date time column in create table command but then also I am getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_RATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_TIMEST + " created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);" //this way works fine
```

Works for both Long and String values, with string I got complete formatted date whereas with long I got a long number which can be useful in manipulating date later on

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a whitespace between `KEY_TIMEST` and its datatype in your create statement:

```
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_RATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TIMEST + " DATETIME NOT NULL);" // space added here
        );
```

Answer (score -2):

You defined time column in database as INTEGER and it's ok since time can be stored as both INTEGER or TEXT but when you trying to insert new row, you give a string to it. Maybe converting the time to Long solve your problem. just give it a try

```
    Date d = new Date(); //gives you the current time. 
    Long newTime = d.getTime();
    cv.put(KEY_TIME, newTime);
```